# Lightweight command-line gapless audio player

Tags: command-line, audio-player

I have a Raspberry Pi project where I'm using a JACK audio mixer to programmatically modulate sounds (using the newest Ubuntu 19.04 amd64 server image). I had assumed it would be easy to find an lightweight audio file player that can loop files during playback without gaps, but I discovered that `mplayer`, at least, does not, and `aplay` doesn't appear to be able to loop at all. I found other solutions, such as [aqualung](https://github.com/jeremyevans/aqualung) that work nicely but require a GUI (and thus X, and a desktop). Can anyone point me to a simple command-line audio player that does gapless playback, ideally with a JACK interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [sndfile-tools package](http://mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/tools/), there's a program called `sndfile-jackplay` that can play any of the `libsndfile` formats, loops, and interfaces with the JACK audio library. It's quite poorly documented, but is easy to use. I can verify that with Ubuntu 19.04, the playback loops without gaps (sample accurate).